# How to get SVG height and width from path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to take any icon and scale it correctly, I can't get the height and width with the icon. I use reactJS, I have the path of the icon and the max height/width it can be (it depends on which is larger). Any help?

I have tried using require but it only gave me the path (which I had). I have also tried to use .getBBox to no effect. I don't have any code that might help, just the path

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide some code of what you have already tried, along with your specific problem?

Comment: Check it! [this type of question asked before Svg in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037007/svg-size-in-react)