# Render Images in tic tac toe app using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to create a simple tic tac toe app using reactjs, with two modes in it: **Classic** and **Image**, in the classic mode I have the options to display **X** and **O**, while in the Image mode, I have the options two display two images which are mentioned below. My file structure is:

```
src
  components
    ChooseGameMode.js
    choosePlayer.js
    GameStatus.js
    Status.js
  images
    connery.svg
    square.svg
App.css
App.js
index.css
index.js
...
```

Following is the code that I developed:

*App.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

import Status from'./components/Status';
import GameStatus from'./components/GameStatus';

class App extends Component {


  constructor(props){

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      board : Array(9).fill(null),
      player : null,
      winner : null,
      gamemode : null,
      /* array to store the ndex */
      order_ndex : []
    }

  }

  checkWinner(){

    let winLines =
      [
        ["0", "1", "2"],
        ["3", "4", "5"],
        ["6", "7", "8"],
        ["0", "3", "6"],
        ["1", "4", "7"],
        ["2", "5", "8"], 
        ["0", "4", "8"],
        ["2", "4", "6"]
      ]

    this.checkmatch(winLines)
  }

  checkmatch(winLines){
    let board = this.state.board;
    for (let index = 0; index < winLines.length; index++) {
      const [a,b,c]=winLines[index];
      if(board[a] && board[a] === board[b] && board[a] === board[c] ){
        alert('You won!');
        this.setState({
          winner : this.state.player
        })
        this.state.winner = this.state.player;
      }
    }
    if(!this.state.winner && !board.includes(null)){
      this.state.winner = 'None';
      alert('Its a Draw!');
    }
  }

  handleClick(index){

    //To render images on selecting ImageMode mode
    const images ={
      connery : require('./images/connery.svg'),
      square : require('./images/square.svg')
    }


    if(this.state.player && !this.state.winner && this.state.gamemode === "Classic"){

      let newBoard = this.state.board

      if(this.state.board[index]===null){

        newBoard[index] = this.state.player
        /* push the last index into the array */
        this.state.order_ndex.push(index) 
        this.setState({
          board: newBoard,
          player: this.state.player==="X" ? "O" : "X"
        })

        this.checkWinner()

      }
    }

    else{

      let newBoard = this.state.board

      if(this.state.board[index]===null){

        newBoard[index] = this.state.player
        /* push the last index into the array */
        this.state.order_ndex.push(index) 
        this.setState({
          board: newBoard,
          player: this.state.player=== images.connery ? images.square : images.connery
        })

        this.checkWinner()

      }

    }
  } 

  setPlayer(player){
    this.setState({player})

  }

  setGameMode(gamemode){
    console.log(gamemode)
    this.setState({gamemode})

  }

  renderBoxes(){
    return this.state.board.map(
      (box, index) => 
      <div className="box" key={index} 
        onClick={()=> {this.handleClick(index)}}>
        {box}
      </div>
    )
  }

  reset(){

    this.setState({
      board : Array(9).fill(null),
      player :  null,
      winner : null,
      gamemode : null,
      order_ndex : []

    })

  } 

  undo() {
    let ndex = this.state.order_ndex.pop() 
    let newBoard = this.state.board
    let prev = newBoard[ndex]
    newBoard[ndex] = null
    this.setState({
      board: newBoard,
      player: prev
    })
  }

  render() {


    return (

      <div className="container">
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe App</h1>

        <GameStatus 
          gamemode ={this.state.gamemode} 
          setGameMode = {(e)=> this.setGameMode(e)}
        />

        <Status
          player={this.state.player} 
          setPlayer={(e) => this.setPlayer(e)}
          winner = {this.state.winner}
        />

        <div className="board">

          {this.renderBoxes()}

        </div>
        <div className="btn">
          <button className='reset' onClick = {() => this.reset()}> Reset </button>
          <div className="divider"/>
          <button className='reset' disabled ={this.state.winner} onClick = {() => this.undo()}> Undo </button>
        </div>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*ChooseGameMode.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ChooseGameMode extends Component{

    handleForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.gamemode(e.target.gamemode.value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e)=> this.handleForm(e)}>
                <label>
                    Classic
                    <input type="radio" name="gamemode" value="Classic"/>
                </label>

                <label>
                    Frontenddevlandia
                    <input type="radio" name="gamemode" value="Frontenddevlandia"/>
                </label>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        )

    }
}

export default ChooseGameMode;
```

*choosePlayer.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Player extends Component{

    handleForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.player(e.target.player.value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e)=> this.handleForm(e)}>
                <label>
                    Player X
                    <input type="radio" name="player" value="X"/>
                </label>

                <label>
                    Player O
                    <input type="radio" name="player" value="O"/>
                </label>

                <input type="submit" value="Start" />
            </form>
        )

    }
}

export default Player;
```

*GameStatus.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ChooseGameMode from'./ChooseGameMode';


class GameStatus extends Component {

    handleSetGameMode(e){
        this.props.setGameMode(e)
    }

    render(){

        return (this.props.gamemode ? 
              <h3>You are playing the {this.props.gamemode} mode</h3> : 
              <ChooseGameMode gamemode={(e) => this.handleSetGameMode(e)} />
        )
    }
}

export default GameStatus;
```

*Status.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Player from'./choosePlayer';

class Status extends Component {

    handleSetPlayer(e){
        this.props.setPlayer(e)
    }

    renderHtml(){
        if (this.props.winner){
            return (<h2>Winner is {this.props.winner}</h2>)
        } else {
            return this.props.player ? 
            <h2>Next player is {this.props.player}</h2> : 
            <Player player={(e) => this.handleSetPlayer(e)} />
        }
    }

    render(){

        return (<span>{this.renderHtml()}</span>)
    }
}

export default Status;
```

When I select the **Image** mode and choose the player instead of rendering the image, its simply rendering the path of the image file into the app. I used `require('./images/connery.svg'),` for rendering the image.
May I know what am I doing wrong, also I haven't used Redux here for state management, as I am new to learning react and redux, can someone please help me on how to implement redux into this existing app, so that the state management can be handled in a better way rather than passing the states as individual props for different components? A general idea on how to implement this and any other improvements or suggestions will also be really helpful. Also, as suggested this is my [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/7qky4x8mx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use images, you do not need to modify your classic code, you only need to update renderBoxes() in your working classic code and remove the conditions for `Image` that you added to other parts of the code e.g in App.js handleClick().

```js
const connery = require("./images/connery.svg"); // or import connery from "./images/connery.svg"
const square = require("./images/square.svg");

  ...
  
  renderBoxes() {
    
    const isFrontend = this.state.gamemode === 'Image'
  
    return this.state.board.map((box, index) => (
      <div
        className="box"
        key={index}
        onClick={() => {
          this.handleClick(index);
        }}
      >
        {box === "X" && isFrontend && <img src={connery} />}
        {box === "O" && isFrontend && <img src={square} />}
        {!isFrontEnd && box}
      </div>
    ));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

To make your question less cumbersome next time IMO you can host your code at https://codesandbox.io/s and just show only the question here.

Comment: Check it out here https://codesandbox.io/s/lxy470l4lz
NB: to see the actual image, you should make sure ur webpack loaders are well set or use svg sprites https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually worked. Also, is there a better way to improve the app by using Redux?

Comment: IMO, for a small application like this, using redux would be an overkill.

Comment: However if you need this for learning purposes you can take a look at any redux tutorial of your choice
e.g: https://redux.js.org/basics

Comment: Is there a way to hot-swap the pieces without the submit button? For eg: if the user selects **Classic** mode it will be "X" and "O"s and if the user selects **Image** mode in the middle or in the beginning of the game all the pieces will be changed to images and vice versa.

Comment: You need to make some changes to how the `ChooseGameMode` radio buttons work
SEE a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxy470l4lz
you can take a look at http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/ to understand radio buttons better

Comment: Thank you so much @Enabulele Uyiosa, this really helped!