# Hotswapping using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tic-tac-toe, hotswap

I am trying to hotswap the "X" and "O"s in a tic tac toe app that I created using ReacJS on selection of a radio button with images without a submit button. All the previous "X"s and "O"s will be automatically changed to the  respective images on selection of the radio button. Is there a way to achieve this? My original post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52826242/4877962) and the codesandbox link can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7qky4x8mx).

***App.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

import Status from'./components/Status';
import GameStatus from'./components/GameStatus';

const connery = require("./images/connery.svg");
const square = require("./images/square.svg");

class App extends Component {


  constructor(props){

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      board : Array(9).fill(null),
      player : null,
      winner : null,
      gamemode : null,
      /* array to store the ndex */
      order_ndex : []
    }

  }

  checkWinner(){

    let winLines =
      [
        ["0", "1", "2"],
        ["3", "4", "5"],
        ["6", "7", "8"],
        ["0", "3", "6"],
        ["1", "4", "7"],
        ["2", "5", "8"], 
        ["0", "4", "8"],
        ["2", "4", "6"]
      ]

    this.checkmatch(winLines)
  }

  checkmatch(winLines){
    let board = this.state.board;
    //let newWinner = this.state.winner
    for (let index = 0; index < winLines.length; index++) {
      const [a,b,c]=winLines[index];
      if(board[a] && board[a] === board[b] && board[a] === board[c] ){
        alert('You won!');
        this.setState({
          winner : this.state.player
        })
        this.state.winner = this.state.player;
      }
    }
    if(!this.state.winner && !board.includes(null)){
      this.setState({
          winner : "None"
      })
      alert('Its a Draw!');
    }
  }

  handleClick(index){

    if(this.state.player && !this.state.winner){

      let newBoard = this.state.board

      if(this.state.board[index]===null){

        newBoard[index] = this.state.player
        /* push the last index into the array */
        this.state.order_ndex.push(index) 
        this.setState({
          board: newBoard,
          player: this.state.player==="X" ? "O" : "X"
        })

        this.checkWinner()

      }
    }
  } 

  setPlayer(player){
    this.setState({player})

  }

  setGameMode(gamemode){
    console.log(gamemode)
    this.setState({gamemode})

  }

  renderBoxes(){

    const isFrontend = this.state.gamemode === "Image";

    return this.state.board.map(
      (box, index) => (
      <div 
        className="box" 
        key={index} 
        onClick={() => {
          this.handleClick(index);
        }}
      >
        {box === "X" && isFrontend && <img src={connery} />}
        {box === "O" && isFrontend && <img src={square} />}
        {!isFrontend && box}
      </div>
    ));
  }

  reset(){

    this.setState({
      board : Array(9).fill(null),
      player :  null,
      winner : null,
      gamemode : null,
      order_ndex : []

    })

  } 

  undo() {
    let ndex = this.state.order_ndex.pop() 
    let newBoard = this.state.board
    let prev = newBoard[ndex]
    newBoard[ndex] = null
    this.setState({
      board: newBoard,
      player: prev
    })
  }

  render() {


    return (

      <div className="container">
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe App</h1>

        <GameStatus 
          gamemode ={this.state.gamemode} 
          setGameMode = {(e)=> this.setGameMode(e)}
        />

        <Status
          player={this.state.player} 
          setPlayer={(e) => this.setPlayer(e)}
          gamemode ={this.state.gamemode} 
          winner = {this.state.winner}
        />

        <div className="board">

          {this.renderBoxes()}

        </div>
        <div className="btn">
          <button className='reset' onClick = {() => this.reset()}> 
            {" "}
            Reset{" "} 
          </button>
          <div className="divider"/>
          <button 
            className='reset' 
            disabled ={this.state.winner} 
            onClick = {() => this.undo()}
          > 
            {" "}
            Undo{" "} 
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

***ChooseGameMode.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ChooseGameMode extends Component{

    handleForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.gamemode(e.target.gamemode.value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e)=> this.handleForm(e)}>
                <label>
                    Classic
                    <input type="radio" name="gamemode" value="Classic"/>
                </label>

                <label>
                    Image
                    <input type="radio" name="gamemode" value="Image"/>
                </label>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        )

    }
}

export default ChooseGameMode;
```

***GameStatus.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ChooseGameMode from'./ChooseGameMode';


class GameStatus extends Component {

    handleSetGameMode(e){
        this.props.setGameMode(e)
    }

    render(){

        return (this.props.gamemode ? 
              <h4>You are playing the {this.props.gamemode} mode</h4> : 
              <ChooseGameMode gamemode={(e) => this.handleSetGameMode(e)} />
        )
    }
}

export default GameStatus;
```

***choosePlayer.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Player extends Component{

    handleForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.player(e.target.player.value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e)=> this.handleForm(e)}>
                <label>
                    Player X
                    <input type="radio" name="player" value="X"/>
                </label>

                <label>
                    Player O
                    <input type="radio" name="player" value="O"/>
                </label>

                <input type="submit" value="Start" />
            </form>
        )

    }
}

export default Player;
```

***Status.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Player from'./choosePlayer';

class Status extends Component {

    handleSetPlayer(e){
        if (this.props.gamemode) {
            this.props.setPlayer(e)
        }
    }

    renderHtml(){
        if (this.props.winner){
            return (<h5>Winner is {this.props.winner}</h5>)
        } else {
            return this.props.player ? 
            <h5>Next player is {this.props.player}</h5> : 
            <Player player={(e) => this.handleSetPlayer(e)} />
        }
    }

    render(){

        return (<span>{this.renderHtml()}</span>)
    }
}

export default Status;
```

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: The code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7qky4x8mx)

Comment: Post it here in the question. Noone has time to look at links. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey, meril! It's not related to your question, but you don't need to create new functions like `onClick={() => this.undo()}`. You already have the function, just pass the reference to it, like this: `onClick={this.undo}`

Comment: Also, you should never mutate the state directly, like `this.state.winner = "None";`. Use `this.setState({ winner: "None" });`.

Comment: Thank you for that comment, but can you please guide me on how to achieve hot-swapping of the pieces in the middle of the game?