# Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an issue in Typescript, where I'm trying to understand how to declare `src={close}` inside `ItemProps{}`. I get the following error:

> Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix this error.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import close from '../../assets/close.svg';

export type ItemProps = { 
    /**
     * Close icon source
     */
    src: any;
}
```

The error occurs in the `src={close}`

```
<img className={styles.close} src={close} alt=''/> //src={close} is 'close.svg'
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Where do you define `close`? Obviously it is not a string, but a function.

Comment: What do you mean? It's supposed to be an icon for a `<img src=''>`

Comment: The stacktrace indicates something else, hence why I am asking.

Comment: This is a way in React JS to use an image/icon

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with the `close` declaration please? Is it imported with webpack's magic like `import close from '../close.svg';`?

Comment: Check the question now ;). Actually, this import is not correct @SkyzohKey

Comment: What is `../../assets/close`? A React Component? An SVG file? Something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. It's an SVG file. @SkyzohKey

Comment: Are you sure you have the right loader in your webpack config? A potential solution might be to convert your SVG to a React Component. Benefit here is that you get React flexibility into an SVG. Con is that if your SVG is huge, it might take a bit of time to adapt it. I can create an answer with the SVG to React Component example ;)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but why not? :) I appreciate the help! @SkyzohKey

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display svg icons(.svg files) in UI using React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it actually is a `string` in runtime, and you just want TypeScript to stop yelling at you, you just need to fix your typings:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

This will tell TypeScript that every imported `*.svg` file exports a `string`. The above declaration should bet put in a declaration file (example: `stubs.d.ts`) somewhere in your project.

Answer (score 3):

`() => void` indicates that `close` is of type `function` that returns `void`, but the `src` attributes expects a value of type `string`. Make sure `close` is actually a `string`, or a function that returns a `string`.

**edit:**
I don't know a lot about react, but apparently loading an svg image isn't that easy, you could have a look a this [article](https://medium.com/@kossnocorp/solving-the-unsolvable-svg-icons-with-react-preact-webpack-4185032f2601)

Comment: `src={'close'}` you mean, this way? @mika

Comment: I'm using React JS, not Angular. ;)

Comment: If you could  add the code where you fill `close` to your post, that would help.

Comment: sry for that thought i was on the angular tag, but it was typescript cheers

Comment: Thank you for the article @mika

Answer (score 1):

```
<img className={styles.close} src={require('../../assets/close.svg')} alt=''/>
```

Should do the job! Import will attempt to import as a function. Using require allows you to specify file paths.

Comment: Seems a nice solution, but I get the following error: `Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node?` I already tried this `const close = require('../../assets/close.svg')` after the react import @Spencer Robertson

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as the OP asked, here's how one can convert any SVG file to a React Component. This gives you much more control over the SVG and even gives you the power to animate it (i.e. react-popmotion, react-animated, etc) or to update path depending on state. Another cool benefit is that this way you don't need any webpack/gulp/grunt/anything plugin to inline SVGs as they are inlined by React itself ;).

First, open your SVG file, copy the code.
Then, create a new file into `components/icons/CheckboxIcon.js` or similar.

Here's an example of a CheckBoxIcon I made for a project at work:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const CheckBoxIcon = props => (
  <svg
    style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}
    viewBox={'0 0 24 24'}
    onClick={props.onClick}
  >
    <path
      fill={props.checked ? '#1E82E4' : 'rgba(0,0,0,.67)'}
      d={
        props.checked
          ? 'M10,17L5,12L6.41,10.58L10,14.17L17.59,6.58L19,8M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3Zs'
          : 'M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3M19,5V19H5V5H19Z'
      }
    />
  </svg>
)

CheckBoxIcon.propTypes = {
  checked: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func
}

CheckBoxIcon.defaultProps = {
  checked: false,
  onClick: () => null
}

export default CheckBoxIcon
```

Then just import it as a regular React component, i.e.:

```
import CheckBoxIcon from '../icons/CheckBoxIcon';

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* My components... */}
      <CheckBoxIcon />
      <CheckBoxIcon checked={true} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

For more informations, feel free to check this article on dev.to: https://dev.to/nishanbajracharya/using-svg-icons-components-in-react-163k