# What is the correct way to include SVG in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I would simply like to render three svg images in my reactjs application. I've come across dozens of articles and posts but would like to know what is the BEST/ CORRECT way of rendering a svg in Reactjs (2019)???

Initially I was using "object type="image/svg+xml" data{...} .... which i've learn isn't the correct way to render svgs.

I then learn "xlink:href" => "xlinkHref in Reactjs" is/ was the best practice for rendering svgs, yet this is not working in my React App.

Can some please tell me if xlinkHref is the correct way to render svgs in Reactjs (2019) ? If not, can some please point me in the direction?

Edit: Update with Solution.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Icon from './SvgIcons';

class PrimaryFourCol extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="full-width-row home-primary-bg">
                <div className="row-container">
                    <h1 className="h1-header text-center lrg-btn-sp">My Skillset</h1>
                    <div className="four-col-primary__container">

                        <div className="four-col-primary__container__item">
                            <Icon name="coffee" className="our-col-primary__container__item__icon" />

                            <h3 className="four-col-primary__container__item__header">
                                Front End Development
                            </h3>
                            <p className="four-col-primary__container__item__para">
                                Making things look good online is my specialty
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="four-col-primary__container__item">
                            <Icon name="stats" className="our-col-primary__container__item__icon" />

                            <h3 className="four-col-primary__container__item__header">
                                Back End Development
                            </h3>
                            <p className="four-col-primary__container__item__para">
                                Powering applications with server-side logic
                            </p>

                        </div>

                        <div className="four-col-primary__container__item">
                            <Icon name="cartrun" className="our-col-primary__container__item__icon" />

                            <h3 className="four-col-primary__container__item__header">
                                Digital Marketing & E-Commerce
                            </h3>
                            <p className="four-col-primary__container__item__para">
                                Social Media, YouTube and More
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <Link to="/skills" className="btn btn--blue">My Tool kit</Link>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PrimaryFourCol;
```

// SvgIcons.js

```
import React from 'react';
import icon from '../../images/sprite.svg';

const Icon = props => {
    return (
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             className={`icon icon-${props.name}`}>
            <use xlinkHref={`${icon}#icon-${props.name}`}/>
        </svg>
    )
};

export default Icon
```

Comment: https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr . this library ships with create-react-app in case your app was made with that. otherwise follow the instructions in the svgr repo

Comment: **See Also**: [How to display svg icons(.svg files) in UI using React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42296499/1366033)

Comment: Please do **not** update the question with the answer - post an answer instead.

Answer (score 10):

1. Update Create React App to 2.0. In **`package.json`** change `react-scripts` to 2.0.3:

   ```json
   // ... other dependencies ...
   "react-scripts": "2.0.3"
   ```
2. Install dependencies:

   ```sh
   npm install
   ```
3. Now you can import a `svg` as a component:

   ```js
   import React from 'react';
   import { ReactComponent as YourSvg } from './YourSvg.svg';

   const MyComponent = () => {
       return(
           <YourSvg/>
       );
   }

   export default MyComponent ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using SVG in reactjs component ,

```
<svg className="small-icn" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16" style={{ enableBackground: 'new 0 0 16 16' }} xmlSpace="preserve">
                    <path d=""/>

                </svg>
```

check with this it might work

Answer (score 0):

React jsx code

```
import React from "react";

const SocialNetwork = props => {
  return (
    <section className="socialnetworks_container">
      <div className="socialnetworks">
        <a
          href="https://www.facebook.com/PitayaVentures"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <svg
            id="facebook_logo"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 32 32"
          >
            <switch>
              <g>
                <path
                  className="st0"
                  d="M0,0v32h17V19.6h-4.1v-5H17v-4.2c0-3.1,2.5-5.6,5.6-5.6c0,0,0,0,0,0H27v4.5h-3.1c-1,0-1.8,0.8-1.8,1.8v3.5 h4.8l-0.7,5h-4.1V32H32V0H0z"
                />
              </g>
            </switch>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a
          href="https://www.instagram.com/PitayaVenturesMx"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <svg
            id="Instagram"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 32 32"
          >
            <switch>
              <g>
                <path
                  className="st0"
                  d="M22.5,0H9.5C4.3,0,0,4.3,0,9.5v12.9C0,27.7,4.3,32,9.5,32h12.9c5.3,0,9.5-4.3,9.5-9.5V9.5 C32,4.3,27.7,0,22.5,0z M22.5,28.8H9.5c-3.5,0-6.3-2.8-6.3-6.3V9.5C3.2,6,6,3.2,9.5,3.2h12.9c3.5,0,6.3,2.8,6.3,6.3v12.9 C28.8,26,26,28.8,22.5,28.8z"
                />
                <path
                  className="st0"
                  d="M16,7.7c-4.6,0-8.3,3.7-8.3,8.3s3.7,8.3,8.3,8.3s8.3-3.7,8.3-8.3C24.3,11.4,20.6,7.7,16,7.7z M16,21.1 c-2.8,0-5.1-2.3-5.1-5.1s2.3-5.1,5.1-5.1s5.1,2.3,5.1,5.1v0C21.1,18.8,18.8,21.1,16,21.1z"
                />
                <circle className="st0" cx="24.3" cy="7.8" r="2" />
              </g>
            </switch>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a
          href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/pitayaventures"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <svg
            id="LinkdIn"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 33.5 32"
          >
            <switch>
              <g>
                <path
                  id="LinkedIn"
                  className="st0"
                  d="M33.5,19.6V32h-7.2V20.5c0-2.9-1-4.9-3.6-4.9c-1.7,0-3.1,1.1-3.7,2.6c-0.2,0.6-0.3,1.2-0.2,1.8 V32h-7.2c0,0,0.1-19.6,0-21.6h7.2v3.1v0.1l0,0v-0.1c1.3-2.3,3.8-3.7,6.5-3.6C30.1,9.9,33.5,13,33.5,19.6z M4.1,0 C2.1-0.2,0.2,1.3,0,3.4s1.3,3.9,3.4,4.1c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.7,0l0,0c2.1,0.2,3.9-1.3,4.1-3.4C8.4,2.1,6.8,0.2,4.8,0C4.6,0,4.3,0,4.1,0z M0.5,32h7.2V10.4H0.5V32z"
                />
              </g>
            </switch>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a
          href="https://twitter.com/PitayaVentures"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <svg
            id="twitter"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 32 26.6"
          >
            <switch>
              <g>
                <path
                  className="st0"
                  d="M31.5,3.1c-0.7,0.3-1.5,0.6-2.2,0.7c0.8-0.8,1.5-1.8,1.8-2.8l0,0c0.1-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0 l0,0c-1.1,0.6-2.2,1.1-3.4,1.3C27.1,2,27.1,2,27,2c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.2C25.1,0.6,23.5,0,21.8,0c-0.7,0-1.5,0.1-2.2,0.3 c-2.2,0.7-4,2.5-4.5,4.8C14.9,6,14.9,6.8,15,7.7c0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.2C14.9,7.9,14.8,8,14.7,8l0,0C9.9,7.5,5.4,5.1,2.3,1.3l0,0 C2.2,1.2,1.9,1.1,1.8,1.2c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1l0,0C0.1,4.1,0.5,7.5,2.8,9.8C2.2,9.6,1.7,9.4,1.2,9.2l0,0c-0.2-0.1-0.4,0-0.5,0.1 c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2l0,0c0,2.7,1.5,5.2,4,6.4H4.6c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.2-0.1l0,0C3.2,15.7,3,15.8,3,16c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2h0 c0.8,2.5,2.9,4.3,5.5,4.7c-2.1,1.4-4.6,2.2-7.1,2.2H0.5c-0.2,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.4c-0.1,0.2,0,0.5,0.3,0.6c2.9,1.7,6.2,2.6,9.5,2.6 c2.8,0,5.6-0.6,8.1-1.7c2.3-1.1,4.3-2.6,5.9-4.5c1.6-1.8,2.8-3.9,3.6-6.1c0.8-2.1,1.2-4.4,1.2-6.7V7.6c0-0.4,0.2-0.7,0.4-0.9 c1.1-0.9,2-1.9,2.8-3l0,0C32,3.5,32,3.3,31.8,3.1C31.7,3.1,31.6,3.1,31.5,3.1L31.5,3.1z"
                />
              </g>
            </switch>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default SocialNetwork;
```

css code

```
.socialnetworks_container{
display: flex;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.socialnetworks{
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.socialnetworks svg{
    fill:white;
    width: 1rem;
    padding: .5rem;
}
```

:)

Comment: why spam? looks like a legit answer