# How to add local Icons to menus in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

Currently, we are using reactjs in our webapp and we are using default icons from ant design, we have a new Icon design and I already added the SVG icons in the Public folder. The problem is I can’t add my local icons from the public folder to routes.ts where the navigation menus are located. I tried adding the file path of the icons value **icon: “../dashboard_poker_cards.svg”** (Please see attached screenshot of javascript object menu). I tried a different way of adding the file path in the value of the icon but still won’t show the local icon

[image]

I tried also importing the file path in the top of routes.ts but I get warning “declared but its value never read.”

---

I added const at the top of routes.ts

```
const dashIcon = require('/dashboard_poker_cards.svg');
```

and added value in icon: `icon: 'dashIcon'`

***Result: 'dashIcon' is declared but its value is never read.***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display svg icons(.svg files) in UI using React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

Give the path like this:

```
icon: “./public/icons/icon_name”


icon: “public/icons/icon_name”
```

I think any of this might work.

Visual studio has some extension paths for .ts so install them then your way of doing will become very easy:).

Comment: Hello Niranjan I tried this adding the file path as value in icon but it won't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import Icon from "filePath/svgName";
```

You can use this Icon in any line of code down. For example:

```
<img src={Icon}/>
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I tried this adding import at the top of the route page with the file path on it and added the Icon in icon: 'Icon' but it did not work. my problem is I don't know the exact way to add the local file path icon in the value of the icon in route.ts

Comment: I think you should move your svg to the directory of the react component and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

First thing to remember is that all filepaths in React has to start with "/", and that forward slash is a static reference to the **public** folder. No matter where in the code you are in comparison to the public folder, all image paths will start directly in public.

So what you should be doing is `/dashboard_poker_cards.svg` instead of going up one level by adding the two dots.

What I prefer doing when working with SVG is creating components of them, to instead import them like any other component.

```
const YourSvg = ({ className, fill }: IProps) => (
    ... Paste your SVG code in here directly ...
);

export { YourSvg };
```

This way you can even give them props, to give them dynamic styling, or change the behaviour any way you want, as well as importing them like this:

```
import { YourSvg } from "src/components/path/to/your/svg/as/a/component/YourSvg.tsx";
```

Comment: I added const at the top of routes.ts,

const dashIcon = require('/dashboard_poker_cards.svg');


and added value in icon: icon: 'dashIcon'  ===== 


Result: 'dashIcon' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: You could try creating an actual component of it, instead of the regular Svg syntax though, to see if that helps

Comment: I'll place the component at the top of the page in route.ts?

Comment: Yes, and then use it directly where you would use the svg path instead, but with React syntax of <Your Svg />

Comment: Do I still need to install webpack to run my local svg icon?

Comment: You need webpack for any React app, if you used npx create-react-app it is already configured for you, so you don't have to do anything. If not, then you need to set up webpack for your app.