# How to add custom svg icon in Ant Design menu (routes.ts menu)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have custom icons in the public folder of the webapp, my problem is I don't know how to attach the file path to routes.ts. In the **icon property** under routes object I can't add the file path of the SVG icon from the public folder (example: **icon:'public/dashicon.svg**') it gives me warnings every time I tried to add the custom icon file path in routes.ts

```
routes: [
          {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'dashboard',
            component: './dashboard',
            authority: [
              'admin',
              'user'
            ],
          }
```

I'm using Ant design framework for my webapp. hopefully you can help me. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add local Icons to menus in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162885/how-to-add-local-icons-to-menus-in-reactjs)

Comment: Maybe this will help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript