# Parse SVG file to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have an SVG file: check.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28.3 28.3"><path d="M25.2 3.638l-1.6 1.6c-4.3 4.3-8.9 9.2-13.2 13.6l-5.9-4.9-1.7-1.4-2.8 3.3 1.7 1.4 7.5 6.2 1.6 1.3 1.4-1.4c4.8-4.8 9.9-10.4 14.6-15l1.6-1.6-3.2-3.1z"/></svg>
```

I want a React component from it; but I don't want any wrapper tag, just

```
<svg>
    <path […]/>
</svg>
```

I know I can do something like

```
const renderSvg = svg => React.createElement('svg', {
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: svg }
});
```

or even easier

```
const RenderSvg = (svg) => <svg dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svg }} />;
```

But I would end up with:

```
<svg>
  <svg>
    <path […]/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this without using an external library?

Comment: If you need to wrap something, but don't want any extra element in the DOM, you might want to look at [Fragements](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Comment: just have as a function component it will work normally, e.g https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-hopper-7k8q3

Comment: @Ma'mounothman no, what you are writing is jsx, not HTML, so is already a react component. My svg is HTML

Comment: @DBS, because of the same reason fragments wont help

Comment: not sure what you want but you can just pass only the `path` tag to your function if you don't want to have duplicate `svg` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display svg icons(.svg files) in UI using React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component)

Comment: Thanks @DBS; not, as I want the svg, not an image with svg as source

Comment: @Nikita : did you have a chance to try out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455995/11299053)? Did it work for you?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes,I'm testing variants of it. Overall it works, but is tricky to find the correct svg loader for webpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your SVG in a separate file, than [import](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs) that as a component, like this:

```
import {ReactComponent as Circle} from "./circle.svg"
```

Following is a demo [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-hertz-oo34f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: this is absolutely right, but… how do you use this syntax with webpack?

Comment: @Nikita : I don't quite get your concern. Isn't webpack used to deliver content of the app within the sandbox I was referring to?

Comment: Yes, and it works on it; but finding a proper loader for webpack is pretty difficult

Comment: Anyway, this is a different issue, I will check this as the correct answer and if you have further advise it will be welcome

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. As for your further concerns, I guess [the one](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr) used by create-react-app or [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader) (right off the top of my head) might perfectly solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks: tried with the first, but not with the second yet. Anyway, should be easy. Thanks!