# How to use an imported image in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native, arrow-functions

I have been programming in React for a short time and I have some doubts about how to proceed.
I have a component that is displaying an imported svg as an image.

```
import Arrow from '../arrow.svg';


    if (!isChecked) {

      config.email = {
        clickable: true,
        image: Arrow,
        onClick: () =>
          inProfile
            ? dispatch(notification(CHANGE_STATUS))
            : browserHistory.push(/checkOut),
      };
    }
```

Now I want to replace the image I have in my project with one imported from an external library that is rendered as follows

```
<Img type="right-arrow" />
```

Here is an example that is working in my code right now

```
  renderImage() {
    return <Img type="right-arrow" />;
  }

  render() {

    return(
      {this.renderHeader}
      {this.renderTitle}
      {this.renderBody}
      {this.renderImage}
    );

  }
```

How can I use this new imported component instead of the previously used image?

I have tried several ways but I can't get it to render.

the last thing I have tried is the following

```
import Image from '@market/image-market';


    if (!isChecked) {

      config.email = {
        clickable: true,
        image: <Img type="right-arrow" />
        onClick: () =>
          inProfile
            ? dispatch(notification(CHANGE_STATUS))
            : browserHistory.push(/checkOut),
      };
    }
```

I don't see how I can use it within this structure. If someone could see my mistake. Thank you very much for your time and help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just a little confused by what's happening under the hood.

1. If the `config.emailAddress.image` is used like so

```js
<>
  {config.emailAddress.image}
</>
```

You should just pass `image: <Img type="right-arrow" />` instead of declaring a function.

2. Right now, with `image: () => <Img type="right-arrow" />`, you will have to call the function to render the component.

```js
<>
  {config.emailAddress.image()}
</>
```

I think the first approach is always easier.

This should also help you understand why SVGs can be loaded so easily.

> SVGs can be imported and used directly as a React component in your React code. The image is not loaded as a separate file, instead, it’s rendered along the HTML.

See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52605225/10246447) for implementation details.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer... "image: <Img type="right-arrow" />" was my first option but doesn't work , thats why I've tried with the function.