# Using custom icons in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am using material-icons in React.js like `import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';`, but I want to use custom icons. How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display svg icons(.svg files) in UI using React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

Here simple example:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import './Sidebar.css';
 import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
 import {ReactComponent as ShopWhite}  from "./icons/shop.svg";

 function Sidebar() {
 return (
    <div className="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar__header">
  <div class="sidebar__headerRight">
  
  <IconButton>
  <ShopWhite/>
  </IconButton>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving you one example that I currently created for my project. Basically you can create like normal react component and inside your return you can add the svg code. There are many svg chrome extensions that you can directly get svg codes from any website.

```
import React from 'react';

export interface Props {
  className?: string;
}

export default class Barcode extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
        <svg className={this.props.className} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 24"><defs>
            <style></style></defs>
            <title>barcode</title><g id="Livello_2" data-name="Livello 2">
                <g id="NAV_BAR" data-name="NAV BAR">
                    <path className="cls-1" d="M5,0H1A1,1,0,0,0,0,1V5A1,1,0,0,0,.89,6,1,1,0,0,0,2,5V2H5a1,1,0,0,0,1-.89A1,1,0,0,0,5,0Z"></path>
                    <path className="cls-1" d="M28,19v3H25a1,1,0,0,0-1,.89A1,1,0,0,0,25,24h4a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V19a1,1,0,0,0-1.11-1A1,1,0,0,0,28,19Z"></path>
                    <path className="cls-1" d="M29,0H25a1,1,0,0,0-1,.89A1,1,0,0,0,25,2h3V5a1,1,0,0,0,.89,1A1,1,0,0,0,30,5V1A1,1,0,0,0,29,0Z"></path>
                    <path className="cls-1" d="M5,22H2V19a1,1,0,0,0-.89-1A1,1,0,0,0,0,19v4a1,1,0,0,0,1,1H5a1,1,0,0,0,1-1.11A1,1,0,0,0,5,22Z"></path>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="4" y="4" width="2" height="16"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="8" y="4" width="2" height="12"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="12" y="4" width="2" height="12"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="16" y="4" width="2" height="16"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="20" y="4" width="2" height="12"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="24" y="4" width="2" height="16"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="8" y="18" width="2" height="2"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="12" y="18" width="2" height="2"></rect>
                    <rect className="cls-1" x="20" y="18" width="2" height="2"></rect>
                </g></g>
        </svg>
    )
  }
}
```