# Display specific elements of an SVG using react

Tags: reactjs, svg

To make a long story short

- I have never worked with React before, but am familiar with other JS frameworks
- I want to use the SVG file here -> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/English_pattern_playing_cards_deck.svg
- I want to use react to show individual cards from the deck, and in turn make a card game

How do I get react to show only one specific card? I know I can split the file manually and then create 52 different files, but it would be nice if there was a way to just use the file as is..

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296853/4512646

Comment: It certainly pointed me in the right direction...