# Dynamically changing src for image in class component

Tags: reactjs, image

I am using a relative path to display some images. I want to dynamically load a certain part of the path from my database (essentially a number like so:

```
'../../assets/img/pictograms/${this.state.pictoNumber}.svg'
```

Which works fine.

Now I want to insert that string as my src for an image component - I am using a custom one called FittedImage but hopefully that will not cause any issues - like so:

```
<FittedImage fit="auto" src={'../../assets/img/pictograms/${this.state.pictoNumber}.svg'} />
```

This however results in no image being displayed whereas this works:

```
import img from '../../assets/img/pictograms/1.svg'
**** .... ****
'../../assets/img/pictograms/${this.state.pictoNumber}.svg'
```

Can someone explain why and propose how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component

Comment: afaik or understand this is not dynamic, right?

Comment: I have looked at fittedImage component in github , it set src as backgroundImage I think this is a problem for svg url

Comment: maybe this link helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css