# How to import SVGs in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to import an SVG in React:

```
import promo from "../../promo.svg";
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot find module '../../promo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Note: I am using typescript.

Comment: are you sure that's the correct relative directory?

Comment: I am absolutely 100% positive

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like
`import { PromoSvg } from "../../promo.svg";` and then as `<PromoSvg />`

OR

`import { ReactComponent as PromoSvg } from "../../promo.svg";` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52605225/4549234))

Answer (score 0):

Simply added this to your `types.d.ts` file in your `src` directory:

```
declare module '*.[format]'
```

Replace `[format]` with whatever image format you are using; in my case, it was `svg`.

My thanks goes out to @tsamridh86