# There is a common way to include icons in a react library?

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I am building a react library,
the goal is to have no dependency but i need icons.

Am i forced to install packages? Can it be a problem for who install my package?
How should i install it in my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how many icons you plan to have.
It depends on what 3rd party libraries you intend to integrate yourself with.

If the number of needed icons are relatively small, I think that best way would be to just add some simple svgs that you could overwrite when using the library

Comment: thanks for your response.Around 30 icons needed

Comment: here a solution to make an icon component with a set of svg icons https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296853/10058705 then i will implement a dictionary of translate icons to make user able to use his icons