# How to use SVG as Component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, svg, components, config, craco

I have:

`import {ReactComponent as IconSaveTag} from 'src/assets/IconSaveTag.svg';`
and use:
`<IconSaveTag/>`

Now How to:
`import IconSaveTag from 'src/assets/IconSaveTag.svg';`
and can use:
`<IconSaveTag />`

I tried researching and using npm @svgr/cli but was not successful

Comment: What's wrong with using `import {ReactComponent as IconSaveTag}`?

What you also can do is create a js file called IconSaveTag.js and paste the SVG code in and export it as a component.

Comment: Is there a way to configure it without using the .js file?  I used: import { ReactComponent as IconSaveTag} .... can export \<IconSaveTag /> but I don't want every svg file to use {ReactComponent as...}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here are 2 links to different ways to use svgs in React.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296853/13664713
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-react/#use-svgs-react

But why don't you want to use {ReactComponent as...}?

Comment: Because I want to know how to configure it.  Every svg uses "ReactComponent as..." which I don't like.  Thanks for the solution