# Consistently displaying SVGs across Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, gatsby

I've been trying to display SVGs consistently across browsers in my gatsby.js app. I've tried two different methods and neither work completely.

## SVG Sprites

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component/42296853#42296853), I created an icon sprite file and made a component to display the information.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import { StyledSocialList, StyledSocialLi } from "./social.styled"

import IconsFile from "../../../static/images/icons.svg"

const Icon = ({ name, color, size }) => (
  <svg className={`icon icon-${name}`} fill={color} width={size} height={size}>
    <use xlinkHref={`${IconsFile}#icon-${name}`} />
  </svg>
)

const Icons = ({ size }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SocialQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          social {
            linkedin
            orcid
            github
            googlescholar
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const social = data.site.siteMetadata?.social

  let icons = [
    {
      src: <Icon name="linkedin-square" color="#000" size={size} />,
      link: `https://www.linkedin.com/in/${social?.linkedin}`,
      alt: "Click to read my Linkedin profile",
    },
    {
      src: <Icon name="github" color="#000" size={size} />,
      link: `https://www.github.com/${social?.github}`,
      alt: "Click to see my Github",
    },
    {
      src: <Icon name="google-scholar" color="#000" size={size} />,
      link: `https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=${social?.googlescholar}`,
      alt: "Click to see my citations on Google Scholar",
    },
    {
      src: <Icon name="orcid" color="#000" size={size} />,
      link: `https://www.orcid.org/${social?.orcid}`,
      alt: "Click to see my researcher profile on Orcid",
    },
  ]

  return icons.map((icon, index) => (
    <StyledSocialLi key={index}>
      <a
        href={icon.link}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noreferrer"
        alt={icon.alt}
        aria-label={icon.alt}
      >
        {icon.src}
      </a>
    </StyledSocialLi>
  ))
}

const Social = ({ size = 30 }) => {
  return (
    <StyledSocialList>
      <Icons size={size}/>
    </StyledSocialList>
  )
}

export default Social
```

This one works in Chrome, but Safari refuses to render the SVG because it thinks the href of the `use` element is a XSS violation.

> data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Z...#icon-orcid from origin https://kyleshores.com. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

## Embedded paths

As an alternative, I tried creating the SVGs by saving their paths so that the data isn't loaded from what looks like a URI to Safari.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import { StyledSocialList, StyledSocialLi } from "./social.styled"

const Svg = ({ path, color, size }) => {
  const viewBox = `0 0 ${size} ${size}`;

  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox={viewBox} width={size} height={size} fill={color}>
      <path d={path} />
    </svg>
  );
};

const paths= {
  'linkedin': "M29 0h-26c-1.65 0-3 1.35-3 3v26c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3h26c1.65 0 3-1.35 3-3v-26c0-1.65-1.35-3-3-3zM12 26h-4v-14h4v14zM10 10c-1.106 0-2-0.894-2-2s0.894-2 2-2c1.106 0 2 0.894 2 2s-0.894 2-2 2zM26 26h-4v-8c0-1.106-0.894-2-2-2s-2 0.894-2 2v8h-4v-14h4v2.481c0.825-1.131 2.087-2.481 3.5-2.481 2.488 0 4.5 2.238 4.5 5v9z",
  'google-scholar': "M21.485 6.666v-1.702l1.235-0.964h-13.368l-8.072 7.017h5.354c-0.010 0.133-0.014 0.253-0.014 0.389 0 1.303 0.451 2.38 1.354 3.241 0.903 0.862 2.016 1.29 3.333 1.29 0.308 0 0.609-0.023 0.902-0.064-0.182 0.406-0.273 0.783-0.273 1.134 0 0.617 0.281 1.277 0.842 1.978-2.452 0.167-4.254 0.608-5.402 1.323-0.658 0.406-1.188 0.919-1.587 1.533-0.399 0.619-0.599 1.282-0.599 1.998 0 0.603 0.129 1.146 0.389 1.629s0.599 0.879 1.019 1.186c0.42 0.311 0.904 0.569 1.451 0.779 0.546 0.209 1.088 0.357 1.629 0.441 0.539 0.084 1.075 0.125 1.607 0.125 0.842 0 1.685-0.108 2.534-0.324 0.848-0.218 1.643-0.54 2.386-0.968 0.741-0.425 1.345-1.005 1.808-1.732 0.462-0.73 0.693-1.55 0.693-2.459 0-0.689-0.141-1.315-0.422-1.884-0.279-0.567-0.621-1.034-1.028-1.396s-0.813-0.697-1.22-0.998c-0.406-0.303-0.75-0.609-1.029-0.926-0.28-0.315-0.421-0.628-0.421-0.936s0.108-0.604 0.326-0.892c0.216-0.288 0.48-0.566 0.788-0.832s0.617-0.56 0.925-0.883c0.308-0.322 0.571-0.739 0.788-1.251s0.325-1.090 0.325-1.735c0-0.841-0.159-1.529-0.472-2.082-0.037-0.064-0.076-0.113-0.117-0.189l3.557-2.917v1.070c-0.462 0.058-0.414 0.334-0.414 0.665v8.042c0 0.372 0.305 0.677 0.677 0.677h0.249c0.372 0 0.677-0.305 0.677-0.677v-8.042c0-0.33 0.049-0.606-0.41-0.664zM14.775 20.571c0.071 0.047 0.232 0.174 0.482 0.377 0.253 0.203 0.425 0.356 0.517 0.463 0.090 0.104 0.224 0.26 0.399 0.472s0.295 0.394 0.357 0.546c0.063 0.155 0.126 0.341 0.19 0.559 0.062 0.215 0.093 0.436 0.093 0.66 0 1.066-0.41 1.855-1.229 2.366-0.82 0.511-1.798 0.767-2.934 0.767-0.574 0-1.138-0.068-1.691-0.2-0.553-0.132-1.082-0.334-1.587-0.6s-0.911-0.638-1.219-1.112c-0.309-0.477-0.463-1.026-0.463-1.641 0-0.645 0.175-1.206 0.526-1.682 0.35-0.477 0.809-0.837 1.377-1.082 0.566-0.247 1.141-0.421 1.723-0.525 0.582-0.106 1.175-0.16 1.777-0.16 0.279 0 0.496 0.016 0.65 0.044 0.028 0.014 0.19 0.129 0.483 0.348 0.294 0.216 0.477 0.35 0.547 0.399zM14.565 14.285c-0.463 0.554-1.108 0.831-1.935 0.831-0.741 0-1.394-0.298-1.954-0.895-0.563-0.595-0.964-1.271-1.209-2.027-0.246-0.757-0.369-1.499-0.369-2.228 0-0.856 0.225-1.585 0.674-2.186 0.449-0.603 1.094-0.905 1.934-0.905 0.742 0 1.398 0.315 1.965 0.947 0.568 0.63 0.976 1.338 1.22 2.123 0.245 0.784 0.367 1.533 0.367 2.249 0 0.84-0.231 1.538-0.692 2.091z",
  'orcid': "M21.039 12.159c-0.446-0.208-0.867-0.347-1.266-0.413-0.398-0.068-1.036-0.101-1.919-0.101h-2.294v9.547h2.352c0.917 0 1.63-0.063 2.139-0.189s0.933-0.283 1.272-0.477c0.34-0.192 0.651-0.429 0.934-0.712 0.905-0.92 1.359-2.080 1.359-3.482 0-1.378-0.465-2.503-1.396-3.374-0.344-0.323-0.739-0.59-1.181-0.8zM16 0.5c-8.561 0-15.5 6.94-15.5 15.5s6.939 15.5 15.5 15.5c8.561 0 15.5-6.94 15.5-15.5s-6.939-15.5-15.5-15.5zM10.854 22.845h-1.837v-12.835h1.837zM9.934 8.668c-0.696 0-1.263-0.563-1.263-1.263 0-0.695 0.566-1.262 1.263-1.262 0.699 0 1.265 0.566 1.265 1.262-0.001 0.701-0.566 1.263-1.265 1.263zM25.021 18.893c-0.331 0.784-0.802 1.474-1.416 2.068-0.624 0.615-1.35 1.075-2.178 1.387-0.484 0.189-0.927 0.316-1.332 0.382-0.406 0.063-1.177 0.094-2.317 0.094h-4.060v-12.816h4.327c1.748 0 3.127 0.26 4.145 0.784 1.017 0.523 1.824 1.296 2.424 2.311 0.601 1.017 0.902 2.126 0.902 3.325 0.001 0.86-0.167 1.682-0.496 2.465z",
  'github': "M16 0.395c-8.836 0-16 7.163-16 16 0 7.069 4.585 13.067 10.942 15.182 0.8 0.148 1.094-0.347 1.094-0.77 0-0.381-0.015-1.642-0.022-2.979-4.452 0.968-5.391-1.888-5.391-1.888-0.728-1.849-1.776-2.341-1.776-2.341-1.452-0.993 0.11-0.973 0.11-0.973 1.606 0.113 2.452 1.649 2.452 1.649 1.427 2.446 3.743 1.739 4.656 1.33 0.143-1.034 0.558-1.74 1.016-2.14-3.554-0.404-7.29-1.777-7.29-7.907 0-1.747 0.625-3.174 1.649-4.295-0.166-0.403-0.714-2.030 0.155-4.234 0 0 1.344-0.43 4.401 1.64 1.276-0.355 2.645-0.532 4.005-0.539 1.359 0.006 2.729 0.184 4.008 0.539 3.054-2.070 4.395-1.64 4.395-1.64 0.871 2.204 0.323 3.831 0.157 4.234 1.026 1.12 1.647 2.548 1.647 4.295 0 6.145-3.743 7.498-7.306 7.895 0.574 0.497 1.085 1.47 1.085 2.963 0 2.141-0.019 3.864-0.019 4.391 0 0.426 0.288 0.925 1.099 0.768 6.354-2.118 10.933-8.113 10.933-15.18 0-8.837-7.164-16-16-16z",
}


const Icons = props => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SocialQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          social {
            linkedin
            orcid
            github
            googlescholar
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const social = data.site.siteMetadata?.social

  let icons = [
    {
      src: <Svg path={paths['linkedin']} {...props}/>,
      link: `https://www.linkedin.com/in/${social?.linkedin}`,
    },
    {
      src: <Svg path={paths['github']} {...props}/>,
      link: `https://www.github.com/${social?.github}`,
    },
    {
      src: <Svg path={paths['google-scholar']} {...props}/>,
      link: `https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=${social?.googlescholar}`,
    },
    {
      src: <Svg path={paths['orcid']} {...props}/>,
      link: `https://www.orcid.org/${social?.orcid}`,
    },
  ]

  return icons.map((icon, index) => (
    <StyledSocialLi key={index}>
      <a href={icon.link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        {icon.src}
      </a>
    </StyledSocialLi>
  ))
}

const Social = ({ size = 10, color = "black" }) => {
  return (
    <StyledSocialList>
      <Icons size={size} color={color} />
    </StyledSocialList>
  )
}

export default Social
```

In this case, the icons render in both browsers, but the size is not respected. The `svg` element is sized appropriately, but the enclosing path is always 32 x 32.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

I don't have a preference for either approach, but I would appreciate some advice on how I might correct this.

#### Styles

In both cases, the styled components are this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledSocialList = styled.ul`
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
`

const StyledSocialLi = styled.li`
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 var(--spacing-1);
`

export {
  StyledSocialList,
  StyledSocialLi,
}
```

Comment: I think for example 2 your viewbox should be `0 0 32 32` since that's the coordinate system used by the paths.  I'm not clear what problematic output you're getting though.

Comment: @James I added a picture to show the erroneous rendering. You are correct that setting the viewbox to `0 0 32 32` fixes the issue. I don't have a ton of knowledge about SVGs. I don't see how I can know what the coordinate system is from those paths. Frankly, I'd rather not have to do it this way, but this seems to be something that works in both Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Isn't the viewBox usually given as part of the icon?  Example - [instagram icon](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/instagram?f=brands&s=solid) if you look at the "svg" tab.

Comment: And so it was. The original was set to `0 0 512 512`. That makes everything too small and `0 0 32 32` works. Either way, thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that works in both browsers is to embed the SVG data into the component so that Safari doesn't think something is loaded from another URL.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import { StyledSocialList, StyledSocialLi } from "./social.styled"

since it thought the data was from some other place
const Icon = ({ name, color, size }) => (
  <svg className={`icon icon-${name}`} fill={color} width={size} height={size}>
    <use xlinkHref={`#icon-${name}`} />
    <symbol id="icon-google-scholar" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="m408 107l0-28 20-15-214 0-130 112 86 0c0 2 0 4 0 7 0 20 7 38 22 51 14 14 32 21 53 21 5 0 10 0 14-1-3 6-4 13-4 18 0 10 4 21 13 32-39 2-68 10-86 21-11 6-19 15-25 24-7 10-10 21-10 32 0 10 2 19 6 26 4 8 10 15 17 19 6 5 14 10 23 13 9 3 17 6 26 7 8 1 17 2 26 2 13 0 27-2 40-5 14-4 26-9 38-16 12-6 22-16 29-27 8-12 11-25 11-40 0-11-2-21-6-30-5-9-10-16-17-22-6-6-13-11-19-16-7-5-12-10-17-15-4-5-7-10-7-15 0-5 2-10 6-14 3-5 7-9 12-14 5-4 10-9 15-14 5-5 9-12 13-20 3-8 5-17 5-27 0-14-3-25-8-34 0-1-1-2-2-3l57-46 0 17c-7 1-6 5-6 10l0 129c0 6 5 11 10 11l4 0c6 0 11-5 11-11l0-129c0-5 1-9-6-10z m-108 222c2 1 4 3 8 6 4 3 7 6 8 8 2 1 4 4 7 7 3 4 4 6 5 9 1 2 2 5 4 9 1 3 1 7 1 10 0 17-7 30-20 38-13 8-28 13-47 13-9 0-18-2-27-4-8-2-17-5-25-9-8-5-15-10-20-18-4-8-7-16-7-26 0-11 3-20 8-27 6-8 13-14 23-18 9-3 18-6 27-8 9-2 19-3 29-3 4 0 7 1 10 1 0 0 3 2 8 6 4 3 7 5 8 6z m-3-100c-7 8-18 13-31 13-12 0-22-5-31-14-9-10-16-21-20-33-3-12-5-24-5-36 0-13 3-25 10-35 8-9 18-14 31-14 12 0 23 5 32 15 9 10 15 22 19 34 4 13 6 25 6 36 0 14-4 25-11 34z" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon-orcid" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="m337 195c-8-4-14-6-21-7-6-1-16-2-30-2l-37 0 0 153 38 0c14 0 26-1 34-3 8-2 15-4 20-8 6-3 11-6 15-11 15-15 22-33 22-56 0-22-8-40-22-54-6-5-12-9-19-12z m-81-187c-137 0-248 111-248 248 0 137 111 248 248 248 137 0 248-111 248-248 0-137-111-248-248-248z m-82 358l-30 0 0-206 30 0z m-15-227c-11 0-20-9-20-21 0-11 9-20 20-20 11 0 20 9 20 20 0 12-9 21-20 21z m241 163c-5 13-12 24-22 33-10 10-22 18-35 23-8 3-15 5-21 6-7 1-19 1-38 1l-64 0 0-205 69 0c28 0 50 4 66 13 16 8 29 20 39 37 9 16 14 34 14 53 0 14-2 27-8 39z" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon-linkedin-square" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="m104 404l66 0 0-198-66 0z m71-259c-1-10-4-19-11-25-6-6-15-10-26-10-11 0-20 4-27 10-7 6-11 15-11 25 0 9 4 17 10 24 7 7 16 10 27 10l0 0c11 0 20-3 27-10 7-7 11-15 11-24z m167 259l66 0 0-114c0-29-7-51-21-66-14-15-32-23-55-23-26 0-46 11-60 34l1 0 0-29-66 0c0 12 0 78 0 198l66 0 0-111c0-7 0-12 2-16 2-7 7-12 12-17 6-5 13-7 22-7 22 0 33 15 33 45z m133-285l0 274c0 23-8 42-24 58-16 16-35 24-58 24l-274 0c-23 0-42-8-58-24-16-16-24-35-24-58l0-274c0-23 8-42 24-58 16-16 35-24 58-24l274 0c23 0 42 8 58 24 16 16 24 35 24 58z" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon-github" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="m475 256c0 48-14 91-41 129-28 38-64 65-109 79-5 1-8 1-11-2-2-2-3-5-3-8l0-61c0-18-5-32-15-40 11-1 20-3 29-5 9-3 18-6 27-11 9-6 17-12 23-19 6-8 11-18 15-30 4-13 6-27 6-43 0-23-8-43-23-59 7-18 7-37-2-59-5-1-13 0-23 4-10 3-19 8-26 12l-11 7c-18-5-36-7-55-7-19 0-37 2-55 7-3-2-7-5-12-8-5-3-13-6-24-11-11-4-19-5-24-4-9 22-9 41-2 59-15 16-23 36-23 59 0 16 2 30 6 42 4 13 9 23 15 30 6 8 14 14 23 20 9 5 18 8 27 11 8 2 18 4 29 5-8 7-12 17-14 29-4 2-8 4-13 5-4 1-10 1-16 1-6 0-13-2-19-6-6-4-11-10-16-18-3-6-8-11-14-15-5-4-10-6-14-7l-5-1c-4 0-7 1-9 2-1 1-2 2-1 3 0 1 1 3 2 4 2 1 3 2 4 3l2 2c4 2 8 5 13 11 4 5 7 10 9 14l2 7c3 7 7 13 13 17 6 5 12 8 19 9 7 1 14 2 20 2 6 0 12 0 16-1l6-1c0 7 0 16 1 25 0 10 0 15 0 16 0 3-2 6-4 8-2 3-6 3-11 2-45-14-81-41-109-79-27-38-41-81-41-129 0-40 9-77 29-110 20-34 46-60 80-80 33-20 70-29 110-29 40 0 77 9 110 29 34 20 60 46 80 80 20 33 29 70 29 110z" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
)

const Icons = props => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SocialQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          social {
            linkedin
            orcid
            github
            googlescholar
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const social = data.site.siteMetadata?.social

  let icons = [
    {
      src: <Icon name="linkedin-square" {...props} />,
      link: `https://www.linkedin.com/in/${social?.linkedin}`,
      alt: "Click to read my Linkedin profile",
    },
    {
      src: <Icon name="github" {...props} />,
      link: `https://www.github.com/${social?.github}`,
      alt: "Click to see my Github",
    },
    {
      src: <Icon name="google-scholar" {...props} />,
      link: `https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=${social?.googlescholar}`,
      alt: "Click to see my citations on Google Scholar",
    },
    {
      src: <Icon name="orcid" {...props} />,
      link: `https://www.orcid.org/${social?.orcid}`,
      alt: "Click to see my researcher profile on Orcid",
    },
  ]

  return icons.map((icon, index) => (
    <StyledSocialLi key={index}>
      <a
        href={icon.link}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noreferrer"
        alt={icon.alt}
        aria-label={icon.alt}
      >
        {icon.src}
      </a>
    </StyledSocialLi>
  ))
}

const Social = ({ size = 30, color = "black" }) => {
  return (
    <StyledSocialList>
      <Icons size={size} color={color} />
    </StyledSocialList>
  )
}

export default Social
```